# Alternative to Ebay Open Source

Tags: php, cms, ruby-on-rails, python, ebay

I'm looking for an auctioneering cms which is basically a copy of Ebay, but just more modern and open source.

I would love it if it would already have a connector to a Big Data DB like Hadoop.

Does any of you have any good ideas?

Comment: Well, i dont find any auctioneering cms under it.